# OpenCV: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

UPDATE: The code compiles successfully on another computer. So the problem is not with the code itself but with the way I have the dependencies installed.

---

If I have omitted any necessary information, please let me know. The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/chicagoedt/revo_robot/tree/development/lane_finding).

The following code compiles and runs perfectly fine on Ubuntu 14.04 with OpenCV 3.2.0 freshly installed from SourceForge using [these instructions](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);
    waitkey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Using the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
 project( DisplayImage )
 find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
 add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
 target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

The following code fails to compile.

lane_finder.h

```
#ifndef Lane_Finder_h
#define Lane_Finder_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

class LaneFinder
{ *snip* }

#endif
```

lane_finder.cpp:

```
#include "lane_finder.h"

sensor_msgs::CompressedImage LaneFinder::findLanes(const sensor_msgs::Image& msg) {
    *snip*
    frame = in_msg->image;

    cv::namedWindow("Display Image", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cv::imshow("Display Image", frame);
    *snip*
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(lane_finding)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp cv_bridge sensor_msgs)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
catkin_package()
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(lane_finder src/lane_finder.cpp src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lane_finder
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

Compile Errors:

```
CMakeFiles/lane_finder.dir/src/lane_finder.cpp.o: In function `LaneFinder::findLanes(sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const&)':
lane_finder.cpp:(.text+0x36c): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
lane_finder.cpp:(.text+0x3c1): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
CMakeFiles/lane_finder.dir/src/lane_finder.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
lane_finder.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2EPKc[_ZN2cv6StringC5EPKc]+0x4f): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/lane_finder.dir/src/lane_finder.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
lane_finder.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles/lane_finder.dir/src/lane_finder.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
lane_finder.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_[_ZN2cv6StringaSERKS0_]+0x28): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why one runs perfectly and the other fails. I suspect that I have linked something improperly, since this is my first time attempting to compile using a header file I wrote myself. If you believe that I have omitted something important in attempting to keep this readable, I have included a link to the github repo containing the full code at the beginning of this post.

Thank you all so much.

Comment: Well, you are getting linker errors so it does seem like something is going wrong in your build process, but I don't know anything about OpenCV and I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you're doing. See if you can pare down your code and libraries until you get something that works; that might help to find where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this option:

`pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`

Answer (score 0):

My pltform:

- Win10 64bit
- QT58(mingw53)

after installing opencv 3.30, I write code:

```
//main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <QDir>
#include <qdebug>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    qDebug()<< QDir::currentPath();
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("1.jpg",1);
    std::cout << image.cols << " " << image.rows << std::endl;
    if(image.data == 0){
        cout << "No Image" <<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Image" << endl;
    }
   cv::namedWindow("My Image");
   cv::imshow("My Image", image)    

   system("pause");
   return 0;
 }
```

I get the error, like this:

```
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x170): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I dont know why, but other functions work well,expect imshow(). And I did add the LIBS:

```
//qt.pro
INCLUDEPATH += D:\opencv\build\mingw\include    

LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_highgui330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_calib3d330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_dnn330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_features2d330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_flann330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_imgcodecs330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_imgproc330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_ml330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_objdetect330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_photo330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_shape330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_stitching330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_superres330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_video330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_videoio330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_videostab330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\opencv_ffmpeg330.dll
LIBS += D:\opencv\build\mingw\x86\mingw\bin\libopencv_core330.dll
```

Comment: Anyone have met problem like this?

Comment: this site is not a discussion forum and your clicked on the "Post Your Answer" button without providing an answer to the question. Please open your own question if you have an issue. But in this specific case, please search for other similar cases or check you linker input like the other answers here suggest.

Answer (score -1):

cv_bridge depends on OpenCV 2.4. Change the CMakeLists.txt to specify:

```
find_package(OpenCV 2 REQUIRED)
```